# Summing an array in assembly x86. On the inputted indexes

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

Im having some trouble adding an array but on the inputted indexes. For example, the user inputs 4 as starting and 6 as ending array so I will have to loop through array[4] to array[6] and add the numbers inclusively. I'm not sure if i can use my array in .data in the my ArraySum procedure. Do i have to push it into the procedure somehow?

I am using Kip Irvine's external library for this.

My code is here:

```
 TITLE Assignment 7

    INCLUDE Irvine32.inc


.data
str1 BYTE "The array sum is:    ",0
start BYTE "Enter the Starting Index:  ",0
endinx BYTE "Enter the Ending Index:    ",0

array DWORD 4, 6, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4
sum DWORD ?
j DWORD ?
k DWORD ?

.code
main PROC
    mov esi, OFFSET array
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF array

    mov edx, OFFSET start
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov j, eax
    mov esi, j


    mov edx, OFFSET endinx
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov k, eax
    mov ecx, k

    call ArraySum
    mov sum,eax
    call WriteInt

main ENDP

;---------------------------------------------------
ArraySum PROC
;sums an array falling within j..k inclusive
;---------------------------------------------------
    push esi
    push ecx

    mov eax, 0
L1:
    add eax, array[esi]
    add esi, TYPE DWORD
    loop L1

    pop ecx
    pop esi
    ret

ArraySum ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have no problem accessing `array` from ArraySum, but it seems that the code for the loop is wrong. The `loop label` instruction decreases the `ecx` register and it jumps to the label if `ecx` is not zero. Also `array` contains DWORDs which means that when you access its elements you should multiply the index with 4.
Overall the code for the loop should be something like this:

```
   ;; array max_index in ECX, i.e. length-1
    push ebx
    mov ebx, offset array
    xor  eax, eax                      ; sum = 0
    xor  esi, esi                      ; index = 0
L1:                                    ; do {
    add eax, dword ptr [ebx + esi * 4]  ; sum += array[idx] scaled index addressing
    inc esi
    cmp esi, ecx
    jle L1                             ; }while(i <= max_idx)

    pop ebx
   ; EAX = sum of array[0 .. ecx*4]
```